# @fontface works on http://www.domain.com but doesn't work on http://domain.com

Tags: css, http, fonts, web, font-face

`@fontface` works when I load http://www.grozav.com but doesn't work on http://grozav.com .

What can I do to fix this?

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-weight:bold;
    src: url('http://grozav.com/font/impact.ttf');
    src: url('http://www.grozav.com/font/impact.ttf');}

@font-face {
    font-family: MisterGiacco-Bold;
    font-weight:bold;
    src: url('http://grozav.com/font/giacco.ttf');
    src: url('http://www.grozav.com/font/giacco.ttf');}
```

I tried putting 2 urls. Didn't work. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What browser? Can you supply a screenshot? They look the same to me on Chrome 17, OS X. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: I can confirm in FF9 Win7 64bit that it's not working.

Comment: I see that you've solved it. I would, however, redirect all traffic from [www.grozav.com](http://www.grozav.com) to [grozav.com](http://grozav.com), first of all because using `www` as a prefix is redundant and outdated, but mostly because otherwise search engines might index both as different pages, and users might get confused because the auto-complete won't work when they've typed `grozav.com/so`, because earlier they were browsing `www.grozav.com/something` instead of `grozav.com/something` or vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why specify the full URL? Just put:

```
src: url('/font/giacco.ttf');
```

It might be a case that `@fontface` doesn't work cross-domain. FireFox has an issue with this.

But if you are using a file from within the same domain, just don't specify the full domain, and just the supply the path to the ttf file.

Comment: In what browsers doesn't it work cross-domain? Seems to be working for me in Chrome.

Comment: @dotweb - See edit. I might be wrong though, but either way this issue can be avoided by not supplying the domain. It doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: This works for switching to https as well, although you *could* go protocol-relative: `//grozav.com/font/impact.ttf`... but that doesn't help the www issue.

Answer (score 1):

Definitively it's the url, but why? Apparently @font-face does not care about cross domain issues but firefox do, so in order to make it work with cross domain in firefox you should set your server (apache?) to avoid this restriction for one or multiple domains, the following page has some info about this:
http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/fixing-firefox-font-face-cross-domain_25.html

I guess the simplest choice is @Curt's choice ;)